# SSH over two hops

Tags: ssh

I have to upload, compile and run some code on a remote system. It turned out, that the following mechanism works fine:

```
rsync -avz /my/code me@the-remote-host.xyz:/my/code
ssh me@the-remote-host.xyz 'cd /my/code; make; ./my_program'
```

While it's maybe not the best looking solution, it has the advantage that it's completely self-contained.

Now, the problem is: I need to do the same thing on another remote system which is not directly accessible from the outside by ssh, but via a proxy node. On that system, if I just want to execute a plain ssh command, I need to do the following:

```
[my local computer]$ ssh me@the-login-node.xyz
[the login node]$ ssh me@the-actual-system.xyz
[the actual system]$ make
```

**How do I need to modify the above script in order to "tunnel" rsync and ssh via the-login-node to the-actual-system?** I would also prefer a solution that is completely contained in the script.

Comment: see https://superuser.com/questions/1115715/rsync-files-via-intermediate-host